# How to correctly deal with a running simulation before a session is suspended?

Tags: process, suspend

I have a long simulation running on my laptop, but I have to travel now and the simulation is not done.

If I suspend my session (sleep), would all the processes continue from where they left off? (it's a python simulation started by an IDE)

Is it safer to manually stop a process before suspending and manually continuing it after resuming?

Answer (score 1):

Suspending the system keeps all processes running. Of course, the processes won't run *while* the system is suspended, but they resume where they left off when the system resumed. This applies to all processes, including the window manager, the screen locker, the script that handles power management, your simulation, …

If you have a long simulation, you should arrange for it to save its state from time to time, and to have a way to resume a saved state. This isn't needed to survive suspension, but it's useful in case your battery runs out or your system crashes.